# GNOME 3 - can't start eclipse no "java" in PATH

Tags: eclipse, path, debian, gnome-3

I recently downloaded `eclipse Kepler` and `JDK 1.7` to my Debian-machine and setup eclipse to be in

```
/usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

and the JDK to

```
/usr/share/
```

When I work in terminal, I can start it just fine.
Now, I wanted to add a link to GNOME 3 applications menu. So I `cat` one of the files, and changed it accordingly. When I click on the icon in the applications-menu I am displayed with

> "either a JDK or JRE must be present in eclipse/jre. java was not found in PATH".

Can I go around putting the JRE into the folder? How can I adjust the `PATH` when I use the applications-menu?

Answer (score 0):

Add your eclipse.ini file:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```